# Heterogeneous Array of generic object where T is different

Tags: swift, generics, collections

this is how my class `BaseSection` which implements `Collection` and it looks like this:

```
class BaseSection<T:Equatable> {

var items:[T]?

required init(items:[T]){
   self.items = items
  }
}

let sectionTop = BaseSection<TopItem>(items:["foo","bar","yo"])
let sectionBottom = BaseSection<BottomItem>(items:["foo","bar","yo"])
```

for this demo i am constructing the section of string objects which are `Equatable` but my project construct object with one property of `String`
collection implementation is not listed here.
i need to hold both objects in array, and cant do it even though their base class is the same.

```
let sections = [sectionTop, sectionBottom]
heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]' add explicit type annotation....
```

im fighting for hours with many solutions but couldn't achieve my goal here.
any help would be much appreciated

```
Edit: I have uploaded the sample code to gitHub so you can get a better grasp of what im doing
```

[github Link](https://github.com/OrAzr/DiffingSections)

Comment: Related: https://medium.com/@aunnnn/covariance-and-contravariance-in-swift-32f3be8610b9

Comment: If you had `sections`, what would you plan to do with it? You wouldn't be able to access the `items` property of its elements, because the type isn't consistent. (Solutions that include `as?` casting everything is a mistaken and should be rethought.) With a sense of what you expect to do with `sections` (and particularly what you plan to do with its elements), we can discuss what type it should be.

Comment: @user28434 Interesting article :)

Comment: I agree with Rob, it is unclear what you want to do with the array

Comment: Sure, im structuring the data this way in order to use it with Differ library to have my tableview manage all updates, deletions and insertions automatically.
the data retrieved from the server is divided for 2 arrays and the elements are so much different, i can make one big object but that is ugly solution.

Comment: That isn't really what I was asking. I mean literally what line of code do you see yourself writing to consume `sections`? You won't have access to `items` (at least not as `TopItem` and `BottomItem`), so what are you going to do with it? Your calling code will drive how you structure it. (Where this is going is that you almost certainly actually want a protocol here, but I have to know what you would want that protocol to do.)

Comment: @RobNapier tableView.animateRowAndSectionChanges(oldData: old, newData: new)
both are collections

Answer (score 3):

becos in swift custom generic types are all invariance, that means `BaseSection<TopItem>` and  `BaseSection<BottomItem>` has no relationship, so the only common type of the two is `Any`, you may follow the links in comment for further info, as a summary

1. Arrays / Dict are covariance
2. closure params types are contravariance, closure return type is covariance
3. custom generic types are invariance

additional, Arrays/Dict are struct, which means they are passed by value, so it's safe to treat them as covariance

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be building is a mechanism for automating table view changes as data changes. Very common. I highly recommend taking a look at [ListDiff](https://github.com/lxcid/ListDiff) for a useful starting point on calculating the changes. (In my own code, I use a rewritten version of ListDiff, so my examples here aren't tested, but they should be very close.)

The goal is to create a set of update operations (copied from the ListDiff example):

```
import ListDiff

extension Int : Diffable {
    public var diffIdentifier: AnyHashable {
        return self
    }
}
let o = [0, 1, 2]
let n = [2, 1, 3]
let result = List.diffing(oldArray: o, newArray: n)
// result.hasChanges == true
// result.deletes == IndexSet(integer: 0)
// result.inserts == IndexSet(integer: 2)
// result.moves == [List.MoveIndex(from: 2, to: 0), List.MoveIndex(from: 1, to: 1)]
// result.changeCount == 4
```

The important thing here is that you have a series of deletes, inserts, and move operations. You can apply those to a table view with something along these lines:

```
extension UITableView {
    func applyChanges(from changeset: Result, forSection section: Int = 0) {
        beginUpdates()

        let deletes = changeset.deletes.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }
        deleteRows(at: deletes, with: .bottom)

        let inserts = changeset.deletes.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }
        insertRows(at: inserts, with: .none)

        for move in changeset.moves {
            guard !changeset.deletes.contains(move.from) else { continue }
            moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: move.from, section: section), 
                    to: IndexPath(row: move.to, section: section))
        }

        endUpdates()
    }
}
```

The key point here is that for animations, you only need index paths. You don't actually need the data. So compute index paths and pass those around. No generics needed.

Comment: thanks for the answer!
did you noticed the structure of my array? it contains 2 array with different objects.
array of ints will be pretty easy to implement

Comment: just uploaded code to github if you mind to take a look https://github.com/OrAzr/DiffingSections

Comment: I'm not certain what to do with the code you've posted. Is there still a question here? Nothing in there seems to require an array of multiple types. I don't even see why BaseSection is generic; it only ever holds [BaseItem], so just have it hold [BaseItem]. You've mixed protocols, subclassing, and generics here. That's way over complicated and is going to bite you again and again. If you need subclasses, just use subclasses. There's no need to introduce generics and protocols on top of that.

Comment: The short answer to the title question is: you can't do that, redesign so you don't need to. (There are lots of generic tableview handlers that don't require that; I build them myself in Swift. See https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit for a really powerful one if you don't want to build your own. It's in ObjC, but interops w/ Swift very well.)